# Getting date from web, returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsurlconnection

Doing a check to get the current time and date from Google.  The first option works although not the best way to do this as it's using a depreciated method and waiting for everything to finish with the synchronous method is not good UX.

```
-(NSDate*)timeAndDateFromWeb{
    

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                    initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://google.co.uk"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = nil;
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&httpResponse error:nil];
    NSString *dateString = [[httpResponse allHeaderFields] objectForKey:@"Date"];
    DebugLog(@" *** GOOGLE DATE:  %@ ****",dateString);
    if (httpResponse){
        hasDataConnection = YES;
       
    }
    else{
        hasDataConnection = NO;
       
    }
    
    // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateformatted = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [dateformatted setDateFormat:@"E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];
    NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en"];
    [dateformatted setLocale:locale];
    
    return [dateformatted dateFromString:dateString];
}
```

Trying to adapt it is almost there although I'm returning nil for my date string: `[dateformatted dateFromString:dateString];`

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://google.co.uk"];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = nil;
    NSString *dateString = [[httpResponse allHeaderFields] objectForKey:@"Date"];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
      if (error) {
          hasDataConnection = NO;
          //NSLog(@"\n\n ----> Not connected Error,%@", [error localizedDescription]);
      }
      else {
          //NSLog(@"\n\n -----> connected:  %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
          hasDataConnection = YES;
       
          
      }
    }];
    
    
    // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateformatted = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [dateformatted setDateFormat:@"E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];
    NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en"];
    [dateformatted setLocale:locale];

    DebugLog(@" *** GOOGLE DATE:  %@ ****",[dateformatted dateFromString:dateString]);
    
    return [dateformatted dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: in second option you get the output in `DebugLog(@" *** GOOGLE DATE:  %@ ****",dateString);`

Comment: Ah yes.  Typo, edited, still no value for date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're switching from sync to async, can't return value the same way as before.

When you call `sendAsynchronousRequest` method, it starts a background task, but your thread continues work instantly. That's why both `httpResponse` and `dateString` are `null`.

So instead of that you should change your return type to `void`, because you can't return result instantly, and add a callback, which will be run when the job is done. And process your formatting in the completion of the task too:

```
- (void)timeAndDateFromWeb:(void (^)(NSDate *))completion {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://google.co.uk"];
    NSURLSessionTask *task = [NSURLSession.sharedSession
     dataTaskWithURL:url
     completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
//            hasDataConnection = NO;
            //NSLog(@"\n\n ----> Not connected Error,%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        else if ([response isKindOfClass:NSHTTPURLResponse.class] ) {
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
            NSString *dateString = [[httpResponse allHeaderFields] objectForKey:@"Date"];
            
            // Convert string to date object
            NSDateFormatter *dateformatted = [NSDateFormatter new];
            [dateformatted setDateFormat:@"E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];
            NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en"];
            [dateformatted setLocale:locale];
            
//            DebugLog(@" *** GOOGLE DATE:  %@ ****",[dateformatted dateFromString:dateString]);
            
            completion([dateformatted dateFromString:dateString]);
            //NSLog(@"\n\n -----> connected:  %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
//            hasDataConnection = YES;
            
            
        }
    }];
    [task resume];
}
```

And so the result of this method will be returned to the block, same as result of the background task.

Don't forget, that it will be called on the background thread, same as the download task completion block. So if you wanna change some UI you need to move back to the main thread:

```
[self timeAndDateFromWeb:^(NSDate *date) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"%@", date);
        // UI changes
    });
}];
```

Alternatively you can move it to the main thread inside your function, right before returning the result:

```
NSDate *date = [dateformatted dateFromString:dateString];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    completion(date);
});
```

Comment: Brilliant answer and very useful explanation, thank you.  Before I would get the return the value of  `return [dateformatted dateFromString:dateString];` with`[self timeAndDateFromWeb]`.  That doesn't work with new block method

Comment: @JSA986 how exactly it doesn't work? you can't see message with date in the console?  please provide the code of how you're calling it now

Comment: @JSA986 - philip answer is correct, only one question, what is the output you get in `dateString`

Comment: The `dateString` is returned in the block fine. The issue, calling it now in another method: `NSDate * date = [self timeAndDateFromWeb]`.  If I define a variable for it, (and have switched `dateString` to the main thread), its `nil`

Comment: I can use: `[self timeAndDateFromWeb:^(NSDate *date) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"%@", date);
        // UI changes
    });
}];` That throws `Incompatible block pointer types passing 'BOOL (^)(void)' to parameter of type 'dispatch_block_t _Nonnull' (aka 'void (^)(void)')` in my other method.  Declaring a variable with `__block` for date always returns null outside the block

Comment: @JSA986 This warning has no sense to me, the problem is probably in how you call it. please share some code with https://gist.github.com/  of how do you call my method. Even with the `__block` modifier you're probably doing the same mistake: checking value content right after starting background task. It's never gonna have value at this time, only after completion block is called. Try using breakpoints where you're getting null and inside the block to understand what do I mean.

Comment: That's the issue I don't know how to call it from another method.  All I want is to return the date like my first version.  ` [self timeAndDateFromWeb];`

Comment: @JSA986 you can't do that without blocking a thread. You better learn how to work with multiple threads because this is used much in most of programming platforms, especially mobile ones.

Comment: My description of what's going is not the greatest here. I'm working with threads fine, in your example, I'm getting an error as described that's with some other code.  You suggested I'm calling it wrong hence my reply.  I think the example I'm using it in (as you have requested) needs to be given so it makes sense with some context.  The date is returning fine in the block.  I will create another question for the other bit.  Thanks